# How to generate arbitrary wallet seeded with eth in hardhat tests using ethers.js?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, ethers.js, hardhat

I'm currently trying to run a test in hardhat/waffle that requires hundreds of unique wallets to call a contract, using new ethers.Wallet.createRandom(). However, none of these wallets are supplied with eth, so I can't call/send transactions with them.

What would be the simplest/most effective way to supply an arbitrary amount of randomly generated wallets with eth? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hardhat allows to seed a custom amount of prefunded addresses using the `accounts`.`count` config option of the built-in `hardhat` network.

Example:

```
module.exports = {
    networks: {
        hardhat: {
            accounts: {
                count: 1000
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Docs: https://hardhat.org/hardhat-network/reference/#config

---

The `new ethers.Wallet.createRandom()` function only creates an account from a random private key in the context of the JS application, but it doesn't communicate with the provider (Hardhat in your case).

Comment: This allows you to create more default wallets, which will all be pre-funded with Ether, but Jaymon's answer illustrates how to set the account balance for even new random wallets that you create, once you connect them to the Hardhat provider, as shown in Ricardo Martins' answer.

Answer (score 7):

I think you'll probably want to use the hardhat network method [hardhat_setBalance](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-network/reference/#hardhat-setbalance), the docs use an example like this:

```
await network.provider.send("hardhat_setBalance", [
  "<ACCOUNT ADDRESS>",
  "0x1000", # 4096 wei
]);
```

I'm not developing in javascript though, but I've been doing something similar in python using [web3.py](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.py) and [eth-account](https://github.com/ethereum/eth-account) with code like this:

```
from web3 import Web3
from eth_account import Account


chain = Web3(HTTPProvider("http://127.0.0.1:8545"))

acct = Account.create('<RANDOM VALUE>')
address = Web3.toChecksumAddress(acct.address)
print(chain.eth.get_balance(address)) # 0 wei

# add a balance of eth tokens to the address
chain.provider.make_request("hardhat_setBalance", [address, "0x1000"])

print(chain.eth.get_balance(address)) # 4096 wei
```

Answer (score 3):

saw this answer, and i think it solves the problem:

https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/issues/686

```
const wallet = ethers.Wallet.createRandom().connect(provider);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I was originally using this implementation, but I had trouble connecting the provider. I solved my problem by configuring the hardhat settings (see below).

Comment: This is the correct way to create wallets and connect them with the ethers provider (use `ethers.provider` in the place of `provider`). However the correct answer for how to fund these wallets was given by Jaymon.

Answer (score 1):

If you require non-static wallets that are generated during test execution, this would be the full solution to do it. Optionally, you can call a [Hardhat Network method](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-network/docs/reference#hardhat_setbalance) to set required balance

```js
// Generates random wallet and connects it to hardhat provider, sets balance to 100 ETH
export async function generateRandomWallet(): Promise<Wallet> {
   // Connect to Hardhat Provider
   const wallet = ethers.Wallet.createRandom().connect(ethers.provider);
   // Set balance
   await ethers.provider.send("hardhat_setBalance", [
       wallet.address
       "0x56BC75E2D63100000", // 100 ETH
   ]);
   return wallet;
}
```